Accessing a data file from a packaged and installed application
The first time my application runs I want to create a folder and copy CI02Data.txt, which is stored in the release folder, into the new folder. My program works fine in development, but when I package it and install from an appxbundle file, CI02Data.txt is not found. What is the correct path to access CI02Data.txt?
if (!Directory.Exists(@"c:\Plan of Study\Data"))
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Plan of Study\Data");
if (!File.Exists(@"c:\Plan of Study\Data\CI02Data.txt"))
File.Copy("CI02Data.txt", @"c:\Plan of Study\Data\CI02Data.txt");

//Get location where assembly is executing

string result = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; 

//Construct a path for the new file
 
int index = result.LastIndexOf("\\"); 
string dataPathCI04 = $"{result.Substring(0,index)}\\CI04Data.txt";

//Copy file to C drive

if (!File.Exists(@"c:\Plan of Study\Data\CI04Data.txt"))
   File.Copy(dataPathCI04, @"c:\Plan of Study\Data\CI04Data.txt");

